# Partial derivative and Total derivative. (First-order; Second-order)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Find partial and total derivatives (first, second order) for function $z(x,y)$
$$
x^2y-y^2z+z^3x=0.
$$

So, the problem is with that zero. I can solve that type of problems, but without zero at the right side of the equation. It just feels like that this zero is meant to change something but I do not know what.
I am sorry for my english. Tried my best to describe my problem.

Comment: There are a couple ways, you can differentiate the whole thing with respect to $x$ for example, giving $2xy - y^2 \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + z^3 + 3z^2 \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} x = 0$ and then isolate and solve. Alternatively there's a theorem that says $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = -\frac{F_x}{F_z}$ where $F$ is the function on the left i.e. $F = 0$. This is just implicit differentiation treating $z$ is a function of $x$ in this case. Now try with $y$.

Comment: Yes. That's it, the theorem that you've mentioned is what I need to solve this problem. Now it all makes sence. Thanks a lot!